# Reporting services with mozilla firefox

Tags: ssrs, mozilla

Is there any good solution to make Mozilla Firefox display well and work alright with SQL Reporting Serives web application, 
I am tired of bugs and stacks produced by IE and theri last versions.
The most annoying thing is size of displayed report in Mozilla is very small and printing control is disabled, I know that is i connection with ActiveX controls that cames with reporting services but I still hoping that maybe I can set Mozilla to worrk fine.

Maybe I also should ask this question on SO to try find a programmers side of story because all of report on my server is mine, So if some one has solution to make things right in code please let me know

Comment: What version of reporting services are you running?

Comment: Temporary I have 2005 and slowly migrating to 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can make it work with the default reporting services control. One way is to use the Web Services side to poll the server for a report and inject the returned HTML into that page. You will still have to manually create all the input fields for each report which is a pain but I think that is the only way to make it work on all the browsers.

This is what I had to do when we needed to support all the main browsers.

Hope This Helps...

Comment: It helps by spearing my horizons, But I do not like showing report in rendered mode such as TFT, HTML, PDF, EXCEL because Doing that I lose a lot of Reports built in goodies, Things like interactive sort, linking to other reports, drill down and others.